# How to send files to node.js server using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io

I am using `socket_io_client` package to communicate with nodejs socket server.
Here is my socket configuration for flutter:

```
socket = IO.io(SocketUrl.url, <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ["websocket"],
      "autoConnect": false
    });
    socket.connect();
    socket.on('connect', (_) {
      print('socket connected to server');
    });
    socket.on('newMessage', (message) {
      print(message);
    });
    socket.on('event', (data) => print(data));
    socket.on('disconnect', (_) => print('disconnect'));
  }
```

Here is logic for file sending:

```
const data = {
            userId: currentUser.id,
            file: file.name
          };
          const stream = ss.createStream();
          ss(socket).emit("send-file", stream, data);
          ss.createBlobReadStream(file).pipe(stream);
```

This is how it would be done from a node client. I need to write dart version of above code. I saw that quiver package has async functions to create streambuffer but I don't know how to implement that for this particular application.

Edited:

```
 void onSendFile(file, data) async {
    final isFile = File(file);
    var buffer = isFile.openRead();
    //socket.emit("send-file",[buffer,data]);
    socket.emitWithBinary("send-file", [buffer, data]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading from the API references and issue on `socket_io_client`'s repo, you should be able to send binaries with `socket.emitWithBinary`.

Assuming you already have a mean to get on a [File](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html), you'd most likely able to do this

```dart
final myFile = File('file.txt');
final bytes = await myFile.readAsBytes();

socket.emitWithBinary('send-file', bytes);
```

**Update**

From the JS version of socket-io client, the `emit` function is able to take multiple arguments, which in the end is [converted to an array](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L142), and so I presumed that you'll be able to achieve the same thing by passing an array to `emitWithBinary` or `emit`

**Note**

Seeing that your JS version doesn't contain any `binary` flags, you might want to try `emit` instead.

```dart
socket.emit(
  'send-file',
  [
    123,
    {
      'userId': currentUser.id,
      'file': file.name,
    },
  ],
);
```

Comment: Even if I do that, there are three parameters to be passed. I still have to send data. Doing this, I might be able to send file but it doesn't take third parameter i.e data. And json Encoding third parameter especially with bytes doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the answer. Note that I did not actually test on it, I'm merely scanning through the source codes of JS and Dart version of the socket-io implementation

Comment: Thank you for going through all that. I tried above solution and it didn't work out for me. I am merely trying to accomplish file sharing through already created chat platform on web using node js. I was told that the data would be of type 'buffer' and stream used was duplex stream.

Comment: Just making sure if you've tested on emitWithBinary. If it's a stream/buffer you want, try reading the file with `openRead`

Comment: I have added my code to the question. That's what I have tried so far.

Comment: It'll be helpful to describe what's not working, does the server receive anything at all? Or the client just refuse to send out the data?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the server as it was done by other party. So I couldn't see if anything was wrong. I added my problem as issue in github repository and they helped me out. Thank you for the effort. You were right for the most part and I had to request for some server modification for receiving part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel
See an Official example https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets
convert file to bytes and sink to the stream

```
final bytes = await myFile.readAsBytes();

main() async {
  var channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://localhost:1234");
  channel.stream.listen((message) {
    channel.sink.add(bytes);
    channel.sink.close(status.goingAway);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried all socket libraries and only socket_io_client worked for me. Using other library, I couldn't even connect to the socket url for some reason.